# Rvm installation by GitBash1.8.3

Tags: git, bash, rvm

when I run the command **$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash** in GitBash on Windows,the rvm cannot be installed,the error message is **Bash 3.2.25 required (you have 3.1.0 release)**  Could anyone give me some advice ? How could I install RVM successfully?

Answer (score 1):

try cygwin - it's not yet fully supported, but you can get newer versions of bash and rest of libs for ruby